# $http.get in angularjs showing "TypeError: boolean is not a function"

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs `$http.get` in a factory to execute an API call.  When I ran my angularjs app, it returns the data.  however, when I looked in the console tab using F12, it has:

```
"TypeError: boolean is not a function"
```

This error is generated from angular.js file.  Please see below for the factory code and the listController code.

Does anyone have any idea why the following code cause angular.js to generate:

```
"TypeError: boolean is not a function" and how to fix the following code to resolve this error?
```

**Here is the code in the factory:**

```
app.factory('MyFactory', function ($http) {
    var dataFactory = {};
    var urlBase = 'api/suppliers/search?&q=';
    dataFactory.search = function (searchString) {
        var urlString = urlBase + searchString;
        return $http.get(urlString)
    }
    return dataFactory;
});
```

**Here is the code that calling the factory:**

```
var ListController = function ($scope, $location, MyFactory) {

    $scope.message = "List.html page";

    var searchstring = 'de';

    getSuppliers();

    function getSuppliers() {
        MyFactory.search(searchstring)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.suppliers = [];
                $scope.suppliers = data.items;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = "Unable to load customer data: " + error.message;
            });
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

`$http` returns a promise.  You need to call `then()` and pass your callbacks to it

```
function getSuppliers() {
    MyFactory.search(searchstring).then(function (data) {
       $scope.suppliers = [];
       $scope.suppliers = data.items;
    },function (error) {
       $scope.status = "Unable to load customer data: " + error.message;
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  I have copied your code, but it still gave me the same error.  Isn't .success (which was what I had originally) does the same thing as .then?

Comment: `.success` is called on an http response that indicates success, such as most of those in the 2## branch. `.error` is called if you get an error response, such as the 4## and 5## branches, and `.then` is called either way. `.then` is a method on any `q` promise (this is what I believe angular uses) but `.success` and `.error` are for http promises.